# Django Reverse Foreign Key FieldError

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to replicate Django's [Each publisher, each with a count of books as a "num_books" attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) using the following models:

```
class Requests(models.Model):
    request_id      = models.AutoField(db_column='RequestId', primary_key=True)
    request_type    = models.ForeignKey('RequestTypes', db_column='RequestTypeId')
    ...
class RequestTypes(models.Model):
    request_type_id = models.CharField(db_column='RequestTypeId', primary_key=True)
    request_type_title           = models.CharField(db_column='Title')
    ...
```

From what I can tell, this should allow me to get a count of requests for each type using this:

```
Models.RequestTypes.objects.annotate(num_requests=Count('requests'))
```

But that just gives a `FieldError`, Cannot resolve keyword 'requests' into field.

Any ideas what I've missed?

Comment: I don't see a `requests` field in `RequestTypes` model.

Comment: What's in the `Count()` should be a valid field name in your model. You don't have `requests` in your `RequestTypes` model, that's why the `FieldError` comes up.

Comment: @ShangWang There isn't a `book` field in the `Publisher` model of the example

Answer (score 0):

```
Models.RequestTypes.objects.annotate(num_requests=Count('requests_set'))
```